# Set Theory - Models

Tags: set-theory, axioms, graph-isomorphism

If $  A = \{a_0, a_1, a_2\}.$  Suppose consider interpretations of the language $\{\in \}$
onto this domain.

Can $M$ be a model of Extensionality and Foundation? 
If so can there be more than one model? 
Can there be more than one model up to isomorphism?

Comment: It would help if you stated the two axioms, especially Foundation. The Axiom of Foundation can be stated in different ways, which are equivalent in the presence of other axioms, but may not be equivalent by themselves.

Comment: Describing *all* 3-element models of Extensionality and Foundation might be a tedious exercise. Fortunately you are not asked to do that. All you have to to solve this problem is find two non-isomorphic models. That should be ease. For instance, for one of them, you could take $$a_1=\{a_2\},\ a_2=\{a_3\},\ a_3=\{a_1\}.$$ That satisfies the axioms of extensionality and foundation that I have in mind; not sure about yours.

Comment: Another simple model that isn't isomorphic to the previous comment is the same as above, only without $a_1 \in a_3$